# I am trying to convert whole values to decimal in R

Tags: r, decimal

I am trying to change values in a data frame in the column "Ratings" from whole (5, 4, etc.) to decimal (5.0, 4.0, etc). And I wanted to use these commands. Can someone explain what 'x' stands for in function (x)?[image]

Comment: `data.frame(value = as.integer(c(1, 2, 3))) %>% mutate(value = format(round(value, 2), nsmall = 1))`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option with `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

Ordered_Temp <- data.frame(
  Ratings = c(1.23, 2.34, 4.56),
  No.of.Restaurants = c(3, 4, 5)
)


Ordered_Temp %>% 
  mutate(No.of.Restaurants = format(round(No.of.Restaurants, 2), nsmall = 1))
#>   Ratings No.of.Restaurants
#> 1    1.23               3.0
#> 2    2.34               4.0
#> 3    4.56               5.0
```